# DreamWeaver CS4: Which Version Control System (VCS) does it use?

Tags: version-control, dreamweaver, perforce

In DreamWeaver CS4 When I go to Site -> New Site... and go through
the various screens I get to a screen named
Site Definition -> Sharing Files
which asks me:

Do you want to enable checking in and checking out files,
to ensure that you and your co-workers cannot edit the
same file at the same time?

If I opt for Yes, it asks me for my name and email address,
*AND NOTHING ELSE* it seems.

What I would like to know is, what Version Control System (VCS)
is employed to implement the options on this screen? Is it DW's
propriety VCS system, or some other. I know CS4 supports Perforce,
but have no idea if this screen was to configure Perforce options
then why is this not mentioned? Which other VCS systems does DW CS4
support besides P4 (CVS, SVN, GIT, Mercurial (Hg), etc..)?

Thanks for sharing your knowledge,

John Goche

Comment: Sorry, I mean DW CS4 supports Subversion, not Perforce. It seems like other version control systems are not supported in this version of dreamweaver, as can be noted from the advanced tab when creating a site.

Answer (score 6):

For the screen that you're talking about, the basic checkin/checkout functionality is not a version control system, it is an attempt to prevent multiple people from editing the same file at the same time. It merely adds a .lck file to the server for the file you checked out. If someone else with Dreamweaver tries to open the file (assuming they also have checkin/checkout turned on) they won't be able to edit the file (well, they can edit anyway and override the lock if they want to). The name and email address are only used to present that info to others editing the site, they can see who has a what file checked out. I think that you can also search through the site to see all files checked out by a specific person (Files panel option menu {top right of the panel) -> Site -> Show Checked out by.

See page 88 of this PDF for info on checkin/checkout, and page 91 for Subversion info: http://help.adobe.com/archive/en_US/dreamweaver/cs4/dreamweaver_cs4_help.pdf
And additional help for SVN and Dreamweaver here:
http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/subversion-resources-dreamweaver-cs4-cs5.html

Edit: There is also an extension for using GIT: https://github.com/ChrisMcKee/gitweaver

You can of course use any version control you want on a site, if you use an external version control client. I've done this for years, and it works quite well, as you don't have to rely on an individual editing application to support version control.

Answer (score 1):

Perforce is supported via the P4GT plugin: http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce_plugin_graphical_tools

Comment: Too bad Dreamweaver is not on the list.